# how to enable error reporting in laravel 4.2 for debugging

Tags: php, error-handling, laravel-4, error-reporting

I just have installed new `laravel 4.2` using `composer`. I make syntax mistake deliberately on my `router.php` to see if an appropriate exception is thrown by the application on my browser screen, but instead a got this

> **Whoops, looks like something went wrong**

.

i have checked the `app/config.ph`p file and changed `"debug" = false` to `"debug" = true` and it is not worked for me. Still I am getting the same message.

**does any body know how to configure laravel 4 to display error message on my screen?**

Comment: First check: app/storage/logs, look if the folder exist and  if you gave permissions to write

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to change `app/config/local/app.php` file - and set `'debug' => true,`

Answer (score 3):

are you sure you set debug state?

because `app/config.php` does not seem right destination for laravel, but `app/config/app.php`

Answer (score 2):

If you are on windows, these additional steps might help.

1. As other users have pointed, make sure on **app/config/app.php**

   **'debug'=> true,**

   2. Go to directory where the laravel folder is on powershell/ cygwin and run:

   **php artisan serve**

and then check the site on **localhost:8000** to access the site. You can put a dummy url to check if it shows error.