# Laravel errors is too misleading ether with debug mode, is there any ways to have more clear errors?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, frameworks

I have a spelling error in migrations:

```
    Schema::create('business_category',function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->integer('business_id')->unsinged();
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsinged();
    });
    Schema::create('business_category',function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->foreign('business_id')->references('id')->on('business');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('category');
    });
```

and I run *"php artisan migrate"*
this error has been shown:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   'brandecide.#sql-42     4_aa' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter table
>   `business_category` add constraint bus
>   iness_category_business_id_foreign foreign key (`business_id`)
>   references `business` (`id`))

this error caused by:

```
        $table->integer('business_id')->**unsinged**();
```

and I should change this to

```
        $table->integer('business_id')->**unsigned**();
```

to fix it.
How should I understand this from the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to enable error reporting in laravel 4.2 for debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731089/how-to-enable-error-reporting-in-laravel-4-2-for-debugging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I understand this from the error?

You can't, unfortunately. I agree the error is quite misleading. The problem is that `unique()` is not a real method. (If so you'd get a method undefined exception)

Instead the call to `unique()` ends up being caught by `Illuminate\Support\Fluent`

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    $this->attributes[$method] = count($parameters) > 0 ? $parameters[0] : true;
    return $this;
}
```

And is then added to `$this->attributes` without doing any checking. This then results in no error but just an attribute (`unsinged`) that will never be used and a missing `unsigned` that causes the constraint to fail.

If you want you can [create an issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues) (with type "proposal") on github. Maybe someone has a good idea how this can be prevented. (e.g. a whitelist of recognized methods)

Answer (score 0):

You probably already have some entries in your `business_category` table. When running that migration, you're trying to add a column that references another table. As you didn't define any default value, MySQL tries to default the value to `null`, but that corresponds to nothing in that other table. When having a foreign key, the value in that column **MUST** correspond to a value in another table.

So to solve it, you could create a `->default(1)`, assuming that the id `1` exists in your `business`-table.